# How can I get the string value from input field?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to implement a Settings dialog for iOS using MonoTouch and the DialogViewController.

The class below contains some public properties, and a method to get a DialogViewController for it.

The problem is that when the view disappears, the string value in `thisName.Value` is null (I have of course filled in something in the text field).

Why?

```
    public class Settings
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public  int MagicNumber { get; set; }

        public bool ThisIsEnabled{ get; set; }

        public Settings ()
        {
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
            Name = defaults.StringForKey ("name");
            ThisIsEnabled = defaults.BoolForKey("thisisenabled");
            MagicNumber = defaults.IntForKey ("123");
        }

        public UIViewController GetViewController ()
        {
            var thisBoolean = new BooleanElement ("This boolean", ThisIsEnabled);
            var thisName = new EntryElement ("Name", "name", Name);
            thisName.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable;

            var root = new RootElement ("Options"){
                new Section (){thisBoolean,thisName}
            };

            var dv = new DialogViewController (root, true){Autorotate= true};
            dv.ViewDissapearing += delegate {
                ThisIsEnabled = thisBoolean.Value; // <== This works
                Name = thisName.Value; // <== This is NULL

                var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
                defaults.SetBool (ThisIsEnabled, "thisisenabled");
                defaults.SetString (Name, "name");
            };
            return dv;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current release of MT.D will not "save" a field's value until the user navigates away from it.  This may be what you are seeing.

This behavior has been [fixed](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/commit/4cffe144f89fc9fbfe032d56e67a8583c2d641bf), but has not been released yet.

Comment: Is there any good workaround? I could probably live with having a Save button.

Comment: try calling FetchValue() on your element before you get it's value.